# Importing (/including) the list of heading of level 1 from one org-file in another org-file

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have the following org-file:

```
#+TITLE: Presentation title
#+OPTIONS: H:2
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS:  noexport

#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \sectionmark{version for header}

#+MACRO: macroTitle special title 

* TODO Hidden section  :noexport:                                     
Hidden text
* Section 1
* Section 2
** Slide 1 :slide:
Content 
** Slide 2 :slide: 
Content
* Section 3 {{{macroTitle}}}
** Slide 3 :slide:
```

When exported to beamer this file generates expected document
with the 'table of contents' slide included, which looks like follows:

```
1. Section 1
2. Section 2 
3. Section 3 special title
```

Now I want to use (cite/import/include/transclude ?? - no idea
what is a proper org-modian wording for this operation)
the above list of sections in some other file.

In fact, what I need is just a numbered list of level 1 headlines  that are not tagged with a specific tag (:noexport: for example) and that are stored in a different org-file.

I believe the other file should look like:

```
#+TITLE: Doc Title
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport slide

#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+OPTIONS: TOC:nil

The table of contents of the presentation is:

#+TOC: headlines 1 :target slides.org
```

however the last line does not do the job. What is the simplest way of achieving my goal? Do I need to invoke some elisp code to do that?

Comment: You might try `#+INCLUDE:` (see [Include files](https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html) in the manual). Whether it'll work or not, I don't know, but I think it's worth trying.

Comment: Well, I've already experimented with #+INCLUDE however I can not make it work as I expect. For example if, I put `#+INCLUDE: slides.org  :lines "9-" :minlevel 1` instead of `#+TOC: headlines 1 :target slides.org` the section headlines are included as \section commands in the final document (tex) and I'm not able to adjust  the font styles of this list of sections.

Comment: Oh, indeed - you just want the TOC. The trouble is that you have to have some sections in order to get a TOC that includes them. I don't know of any way to do that, short of an export filter (basically one that  deletes the offending \section commands). See [Filters](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html)

Comment: In fact, what I need is just a numbered list of level 1 parsed (note using macro in one of the headlines) headlines of level one that are not tagged with a specific tag (:noexport: for example) and that are stored in a different org-file. I guess it can be achieved by filtering functions however, as for now, I don't fully comprehend the idea of org-mode filters. Emacs is so overwhelming...!

Comment: You might want to add that comment to the question: it would be useful I think to make the question self contained and specifying *what* you want rather than *how* to do it might elicit useful responses.

Comment: This solution is so funky I don't dare to post it as reply. Add this macro `#+MACRO: toc-list (eval (with-temp-buffer (insert (org-export-string-as (format "%s\n#+INCLUDE: \"%s\"" $1 $2) 'ascii)) (beginning-of-buffer) (search-forward "Table of Contents") (next-line 3) (beginning-of-line) (buffer-substring (point) (progn (re-search-forward "^$") (point)))))` and then call it with this `{{{toc-list(#+OPTIONS: toc:1,test.org)}}}` where you want it to insert the list of headlines.

Comment: It works indeed. Thank you! I've started my own, very coarse implementation which comes down to looping over headings with `org-forward-heading-same-level` and `orq-ctrl-c-minus`-ing each heading to turn it into a list item, however I stumbled upon another problems... I'll post it when I finish, yet now, when your solution works, my motivation to accomplish it dropped down...